# Dimension too large for confusion matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices

I am trying to create a multi class confusion matrix, however, there is an error in the execution that says "Dimension too large", Is there a way I can overcome this ?

```
   \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
    \usepackage{ifthen}
    \usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    %The matrix in numbers
    %Horizontal target class
    %Vertical output class
    \centering
    \def\myConfMat{{
    {5737,290,507,41,753,926,62},  %row 1
    {3940,3411,5715,168,618,3692,829},  %row 2
    {114,105,1392,5,159,377,352},  %row 3
    {8,13,235,17448,1327,4138,269},  %row 4
    {1467,37,456,790,39466,19298,312},  %row 5
    {837,584 ,2817,5429,8891,36916,1737},  %row 6
    {174,109,2289,959,1617,7091,2035},  %row 7
    }}
    
    
    \def\classNames{{"A","B","C","D","E","F","G"}} %class names. Adapt at will
    
    \def\numClasses{7} %number of classes. Could be automatic, but you can change it for tests.
    
    \def\myScale{1.2} % 1.5 is a good scale. Values under 1 may need smaller fonts!
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        scale = \myScale,
        %font={\scriptsize}, %for smaller scales, even \tiny may be useful
        ]
    
    \tikzset{vertical label/.style={rotate=90,anchor=east}}   % usable styles for below
    \tikzset{diagonal label/.style={rotate=45,anchor=north east}}
    
    \foreach \y in {1,...,\numClasses} %loop vertical starting on top
    {
        % Add class name on the left
        \node [anchor=east] at (0.4,-\y) {\pgfmathparse{\classNames[\y-1]}\pgfmathresult}; 
        
        \foreach \x in {1,...,\numClasses}  %loop horizontal starting on left
        {
    %---- Start of automatic calculation of totSamples for the column ------------   
        \def\totSamples{0}
        \foreach \ll in {1,...,\numClasses}
        {
            \pgfmathparse{\myConfMat[\ll-1][\x-1]}   %fetch next element
            \xdef\totSamples{\totSamples+\pgfmathresult} %accumulate it with previous sum
            %must use \xdef fro global effect otherwise lost in foreach loop!
        }
        \pgfmathparse{\totSamples} \xdef\totSamples{\pgfmathresult}  % put the final sum in variable
    %---- End of automatic calculation of totSamples ----------------
        
        \begin{scope}[shift={(\x,-\y)}]
            \def\mVal{\myConfMat[\y-1][\x-1]} % The value at index y,x (-1 because of zero indexing)
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\r}{\mVal}   %
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\p}{round(\r/\totSamples*100)}
            \coordinate (C) at (0,0);
            \ifthenelse{\p<50}{\def\txtcol{black}}{\def\txtcol{white}} %decide text color for contrast
            \node[
                draw,                 %draw lines
                text=\txtcol,         %text color (automatic for better contrast)
                align=center,         %align text inside cells (also for wrapping)
                fill=black!\p,        %intensity of fill (can change base color)
                minimum size=\myScale*10mm,    %cell size to fit the scale and integer dimensions (in cm)
                inner sep=0,          %remove all inner gaps to save space in small scales
                ] (C) {\r\\\p\%};     %text to put in cell (adapt at will)
            %Now if last vertical class add its label at the bottom
            \ifthenelse{\y=\numClasses}{
            \node [] at ($(C)-(0,0.75)$) % can use vertical or diagonal label as option
            {\pgfmathparse{\classNames[\x-1]}\pgfmathresult};}{}
        \end{scope}
        }
    }
    %Now add x and y labels on suitable coordinates
    \coordinate (yaxis) at (-0.85,0.5-\numClasses/2);  %must adapt if class labels are wider!
    \coordinate (xaxis) at (0.5+\numClasses/2, -\numClasses-1.25); %id. for non horizontal labels!
    \node [vertical label] at (yaxis) {Actual Class};
    \node []               at (xaxis) {Predicted Class};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the reason explained by F. Pantigny, the confusion matrix cannot be processed as is.

However, in this case, when all the elements in the array are divided by 10, each element and the accumulated totals remains below the limit.

The percentages will be calculated --almost-- correctly. (Some loss of precision occurs due to the truncation)

For the final result, the decimal point was extracted.

This renormalization (now done by hand) should be done forehand to the original data, scaling them by an appropriate number.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{tikz}      

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc}


\usepackage{xstring} % added to extract the . <<<<<

\begin{document}

    %The matrix in numbers
    %Horizontal target class
    %Vertical output class
    \centering
%   \def\myConfMat{{
%       {5737,290,507,41,753,926,62},  %row 1
%   {3940,3411,5715,168,618,3692,829},  %row 2
%   {114,105,1392,5,159,377,352},  %row 3
%   {8,13,235,17448,1327,4138,269},  %row 4
%   {1467,37,456,790,39466,19298,312},  %row 5
%   {837,584 ,2817,5429,8891,36916,1737},  %row 6
%   {174,109,2289,959,1617,7091,2035},  %row 7
%   }}

    \def\myConfMat{% divided by 10
        { 
            {573.7,29.0,50.7,4.1,75.3,92.6,6.2},  %row 1
            {394.0,341.1,571.5,16.8,61.8,369.2,82.9},  %row 2
            {11.4,10.5,139.2,.5,15.9,37.7,35.2},  %row 3
            {.8,1.3,23.5,1744.8,132.7,413.8,26.9},  %row 4
            {146.7,3.7,45.6,79.0,946.6,1929.8,31.2},  %row 5
            {83.7,58.4 ,281.7,542.9,889.1,3691.6,173.7},  %row 6
            {17.4,10.9,228.9,95.9,161.7,709.1,203.5},  %row 7
    }}
    
    
    \def\classNames{{"A","B","C","D","E","F","G"}} %class names. Adapt at will  

    \def\numClasses{7} %number of classes. Could be automatic, but you can change it for tests.
    
    \def\myScale{1.2} % 1.5 is a good scale. Values under 1 may need smaller fonts!
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        scale = \myScale,
        %font={\scriptsize}, %for smaller scales, even \tiny may be useful
        ]
        
        \tikzset{vertical label/.style={rotate=90,anchor=east}}   % usable styles for below
        \tikzset{diagonal label/.style={rotate=45,anchor=north east}}
        
        \foreach \y in {1,...,\numClasses} %loop vertical starting on top
        {
            % Add class name on the left
            \node [anchor=east] at (0.4,-\y) {\pgfmathparse{\classNames[\y-1]}\pgfmathresult};          
            \foreach \x in {1,...,\numClasses}  %loop horizontal starting on left
            {
                %---- Start of automatic calculation of totSamples for the column ------------  
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\totSamples}{0}
                \foreach \ll in {1,...,\numClasses}
                {
                      \pgfmathsetmacro{\tmp}{\totSamples+ \myConfMat[\ll-1][\x-1]} %accumulate it with previous
                      \global\let\totSamples\tmp% put the final sum in variable
                }
                %---- End of automatic calculation of totSamples ----------------               
                \begin{scope}[shift={(\x,-\y)}]
                    \pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{\myConfMat[\y-1][\x-1]}   %                            
                    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\p}{round(\r/\totSamples*100)}
                    \coordinate (C) at (0,0);
                    \ifthenelse{\p<50}{\def\txtcol{black}}{\def\txtcol{white}} %decide text color for contrast
                    \node[
                    draw,                 %draw lines
                    text=\txtcol,         %text color (automatic for better contrast)
                    align=center,         %align text inside cells (also for wrapping)
                    fill=black!\p,        %intensity of fill (can change base color)
                    minimum size=\myScale*10mm,    %cell size to fit the scale and integer dimensions (in cm)
                    inner sep=0,          %remove all inner gaps to save space in small scales
                    ] (C) {\StrSubstitute{\r}{.}{}\\\p\%};     %text to put in cell (adapt at will)
                    %Now if last vertical class add its label at the bottom
                    \ifthenelse{\y=\numClasses}{
                        \node [] at ($(C)-(0,0.75)$) % can use vertical or diagonal label as option
                        {\pgfmathparse{\classNames[\x-1]}\pgfmathresult};}{}
                \end{scope}
            }
        }
        %Now add x and y labels on suitable coordinates
        \coordinate (yaxis) at (-0.85,0.5-\numClasses/2);  %must adapt if class labels are wider!
        \coordinate (xaxis) at (0.5+\numClasses/2, -\numClasses-1.25); %id. for non horizontal labels!
        \node [vertical label] at (yaxis) {Actual Class};
        \node []               at (xaxis) {Predicted Class};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the documentation of PGF/Tikz (`pgfmanual.pdf`) for version 3.1.4b, p. 1011, we read:

> It should be noted that all calculations must not exceed ±16383.99999
> at any point, because the underlying computations rely on TEX
> dimensions.

The total of the numbers of the fourth column of your array is greater than that value...

Maybe you should try to use the `fpu` described in the documentation of PGF/Tikz or use the floating points of `expl3` (the programming layer of LaTeX3).